# After using Navigator.geolocation API on IE 11, How do we prevent HTTP POST to inference.location.live.net?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, navigator

We have started using Navigator.geolocation API on IE 11 with HTML 5 and started seeing a HTTP POST call is being made from no where to the URL "https://inference.location.live.net/inferenceservice/v21/Pox/GetLocationUsingFingerprint", I need help in understanding that which API fires this particular call (IE 11 / geolocation API) and how do we not send request with geolocation functionality intact.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP POST call cannot be removed as it's performing the actual Geolocation from available network information (IP address and nearby WiFi networks)

Chrome and Firefox also submit data to an HTTP endpoint. In fact, both use the same service: Google Location Services

From [Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en):

> If you let Chrome share your location with a site, Chrome sends information to Google Location Services to get an estimate of where you are. Chrome can then share that info with the site that wants your location.

From [Firefox Location-Aware Browsing](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/):

> By default, Firefox uses Google Location Services to determine your location by sending:
>
> - your computer’s IP address,
> - information about the nearby wireless access points, and
> - a random client identifier, which is assigned by Google, that expires every 2 weeks

Comment: Thanks Richard for the reply , is Navigator.geolocation making this call ??  since we don’t control this particular host inference.location.live.net, should we need to get registered with Microsoft and establish API interaction with API keys or something?? Please advice.

Comment: @Raju It's an implementation detail of the browser. You don't need to obtain any API keys for it.